# Why should a language prefer indentation over explicit markers for blocks?

Tags: programming-languages, language-agnostic, language-design

I am learning Haskell, and I was looking for an auto indentation tool. I didn't look much, and learned that in Haskell (as in Python), indentation signifies a block. As a result, I'm guessing that it's impossible to create an auto formatting tool, as strong as in other languages in the C family, that use explicit markers, such as { } (curly braces) or `begin` `end` keywords.

I do not mind a language enforcing indentation for readability, but I cannot understand the benefits over both enforcing indentation and having some explicit marker, so that automated tools, can understand what belongs in which block.

If the preference of indentation marking a block, is so that code *looks* better, then I still don't understand the advantage. Given that tabs and spaces are represented differently in different editors and different fonts (mono-space fonts for example look tidier), it's infeasible to expect the programmer to present the code decently. A tool that can take into account the current text editor, would be much more appropriate to format the code correctly.

Why would a language designer choose indentation over explicit block markers?

Comment: Not an answer, but Haskell makes whitespace sensitivity a _lot_ more optional than python. You can use semicolons for most things, and wrap blocks in curly braces if desired. `let x =1; y = 2; z = 3` is completely valid, as is `do { putStrLn $ show x; putStrLn $ show y; putStrLn $ show z; }`. Those don't need to be on the same line.

Comment: [Why Python’s whitespace rule is right](https://unspecified.wordpress.com/2011/10/18/why-pythons-whitespace-rule-is-right/)

Comment: [Python: Myths about Indentation](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/block_indentation.hawk)

Comment: Thank you, @Robert Harvey, I've read those two and that's why I made this post. It certainly doesn't cover me. These prove that it's not a huge hindrance, and ok I'm game, but why would Haskell's/Python's designer(s) choose that road over {} ?

Comment: "it's impossible to create an auto formatting tool" - actually, there is no need for such an auto formatting tool in Python because of the indentation rules.

Comment: Um, increasing indentation *is* an explicit block marker.

Comment: @DocBrown An auto-formatting tool help you double-check what you wrote with grouping constructs, which is not possible in Python and IMO not a good thing. Grouping constructs are for tools, and indentation for the human.

Comment: @DocBrown lol yes, exactly. Hadn't thought of it that way.

Comment: @K.Gkinis: The best source for the *exact* motivations behind a language design decision are the language designers themselves.

Comment: This question is not actually subjective. It asks why some language designers chose a certain syntax. This can be answered. If the question had asked which syntax is *best*, it would be subjective.

Comment: @JacquesB yes, it can be answered, but only by the language designers themselves. As it stands there are some quotes from the language designers, but there is a bit of interpretation in the given answer, which is subjective. So, unless the language designers come in and answer this question (or can be quoted answering this question directly), the answers will be interprestations and thus subjective.

Comment: I wonder that noone has already mentioned this: The block markers were meant for the compiler, but the indentation is for the human reader. Now imagine designing a language and building a compiler on limited machines as a PDP or an 8086 PC - would you want to cope with interpreting indentation as blocks? The markers are there for historical reasons, but are redundant to the indentation which any decent programmer is applying since memory is cheap enough to not care for the spaces in source code, in order to make his life a little bit easier.

Comment: @MiguelvandeLaar The language designers can post here (it has happened before), so that's still not a subjective question.

Comment: @AndresF. I also disagree with majority close reason. My vote was [too broad](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6490#6490) and I believe it's the [right one here](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/300781/31260): "There are many reasons why a particular language feature in a language might..." etc. It is even more so given that question asks about multiple languages, Haskell, Python, "C family" (didn't flag to mod to reclose as broad only because I can't figure compelling words to justify their involvement here)

Comment: If you start with 'def' and end with a colon, why can't the next line auto-indent?

Comment: @MiguelvandeLaar: Can questions about the LSP only be answered by  Barbara Liskov herself? Surely if the reasons for the syntax design decision in question has been documented in the language FAQ this question is answerable.

Comment: BTW this question asks "Why would you, if you were developing a new language, choose significant indentation?" not why the creators of python/haskell/F#/etc chose it. Although, answering why those people chose it, is still a valid answer. It's about "when is this a good practice / correct choice".

Comment: The } violates DRY(Don't repeat yourself), as you use indentation anyway to mark your blocks, and its called "Optimizing the common case"/"Convention over configuration".  Also you don't have to choose between if(cond) st else st and if(cond) {st} else {st} so it makes editing easier in some cases (although copy/pasting is slightly harder), sometimes you can add an extra { } or delete an extra { } and with whitespace you don't have to worry about that.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### Guido Von Rossum

From [an interview with Guido Van Rossum](https://impythonist.wordpress.com/2014/02/16/open-heart-with-guido-van-rosuuma-lost-interview-of-python-creator-part2/), which can be seen in fulltext [with books.google.com](https://books.google.com/books?id=bIxWAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA34&lpg=PA33&ots=2NfKqQR8bW&focus=viewport&dq=The+choice+of+indentation+for+grouping+was+not+a+novel+concept+in+Python%3B+I+inherited+this+from+ABC,+but+it+also+occurred+in+occam,+an+older+language&hl=fr#v=onepage&q=The%20choice%20of%20indentation%20for%20grouping%20was%20not%20a%20novel%20concept%20in%20Python%3B%20I%20inherited%20this%20from%20ABC%2C%20but%20it%20also%20occurred%20in%20occam%2C%20an%20older%20language&f=false) (emphasis mine):

> The choice of indentation for grouping was not a novel concept in Python; **I inherited this from ABC**, but it also occurred in occam, an older language. I don't know if the ABC authors got the idea from occam, or invented it independently, or if there was a common ancestor. Of course, I could have chose not to follow ABC’s lead, as I did in other areas (e.g., ABC used uppercase for language keywords and procedure names, an idea I did not copy), **but I had come to like the feature** quite a bit while using ABC, **as it seemed to do away with a certain type of pointless debate common amongst C** users at the time, about **where to place the curly braces**.

Von Rossum was heavily inspired from [ABC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABC_(programming_language)), and even though he did not have to copy all of it, the use of indentation was kept because it could be beneficial in avoiding religious wars.

> I also was well aware that **readable code uses indentation voluntarily anyway** to indicate grouping, and **I had come across subtle bugs in code where the indentation disagreed with the syntactic grouping** using curly braces—the programmer and any reviewers had assumed that the indentation matched the grouping and therefore not noticed the bug. Again, a long debugging session taught a valuable lesson.

Rossum also witnessed bugs due to inconsistency between grouping and indent, and apparently though that relying on indentation only to structure the code would be safer from programming errors<sup>**1**</sup>.

### Donald E. Knuth & Peter J. Landin

In the referenced interview, Guido mentions Don Knuth's idea of using indentation. This is detailed in [The Knuth Indentation Quote rediscovered](https://web.archive.org/web/20140326035126/http://www.oreillynet.com/onlamp/blog/2003/03/the_knuth_indentation_quote_re.html), which quotes [Structured Programming with goto Statements](https://www.cs.sjsu.edu/~mak/CS185C/KnuthStructuredProgrammingGoTo.pdf). Knuth also references Peter John Landin's [The next 700 programming languages](http://www.inf.ed.ac.uk/teaching/courses/epl/Landin66.pdf) (see the Discussion section about indentation). Landin designed [ISWIM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISWIM) which looks like the first language with indentation instead of begin/end blocks. Those papers are more about the feasibility of using indentation for structuring programs rather that actual arguments in favor of doing so.

---

<sub>**1.** I think that this is in fact an argument in *favor* of having both grouping constructs and auto-formatting, in order to catch and recover from programming errors, which are bound to happen. If you screw up your indentation in Python, the person who debugs your code will have to guess which is correct:</sub>

```py
if (test(x)):
  foo(x)
  bar(x)
```

<sub>*Shall `bar` always be called or only if the test succeed?*</sub>

<sub>Grouping constructs add a level of redundancy that help you spot a mistake when you auto-indent your code. In C, the equivalent code can be auto-indented as follows:</sub>

```c
if (test(x))
  foo(x);
bar(x);
```

<sub>If I intended for `bar` to be at the same level as `foo`, then auto-indenting based on the code structure let me see that there is something wrong that can be fixed by adding braces around `foo` and `bar`.</sub>

<sub>In [Python: Myths about Indentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20180218162410/http://www.secnetix.de/~olli/Python/block_indentation.hawk), there is a supposedly bad example from C:</sub>

```c
/*  Warning:  bogus C code!  */

if (some condition)
        if (another condition)
                do_something(fancy);
else
        this_sucks(badluck);
```

<sub>That's the same case as above, in Emacs, I highlight the whole block/function, press Tab, and then all the code is reindented. The discrepancy between human indentation and code structure tells me something is off (that and the preceding comment!).</sub>

<sub>Besides, the intermediate code where indentation is off in C simply does not make it through the master branch, all the style checks in place would make GCC/Jenkins scream at me. I recently had a problem similar to the one described above in Python, with a statement off by one level of indentation. Sometimes I have code in C that goes beyond a closing brace, but then I hit Tab and the code indents "wrongly": that's one more chance to see the bug.</sub>

Comment: "To avoid religious wars..." I'm surprised that the true reason is so trivial.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: The emphasis on that phrase is by coredump, not by van Rossum. It is not the primary reason if you read the van Rossum quote in context.

Comment: @JacquesB Please tell me what context is missing from the quote, so that I can edit the answer.

Comment: @coredump: Your choice of bolding (which is not in the original source) make it seem like the primary reason is to avoid debate about where to place the brace. But if you read the quote in the original context (without misleading bolding) it is pretty clear that this is only an afterthought, and the primary reason is readability and avoiding bugs due to misleading indentation.

Comment: @JacquesB I hope the new edit is a little less misleading

Comment: @coredump: Yeah, less misleading now, although your decision to bold so many phrases but not the point about readable code shows you have different focus than van Rossum who have many times stated that readability was a primary concern in designing the language. I guess the least misleading would be to bold everything :)

Comment: I don't get you personal comment though: If you screw up indentation in Python, then you have a bug. If you screw up braces in C you have a bug. If you use auto-indenting it is exactly the same in both languages. And if you don't use auto-indenting, the bug can be sneakily hidden in C in a way that is not possible in Python.

Comment: @JacquesB You can screw up badly in both languages. The difference is that in C groupings and indentation cross-validate each other. You have a chance to spot a misplaced brace if all the text around it gets moved to the left or right unexpectedly, whereas in Python, the equivalent of a misplaced brace, bad indentation, offer no other visual clue (even though I consider C more dangerous, for other reasons). C compilers come with warning flags for stylistic issues, like `-Wmisleading-indent` which is just an additional consistency check.

Comment: In Ada, for example, you constantly have to change more than one thing (declaration and use, blocks and indentation, spec and body). When you have an inconsistent state, the compiler is more than happy to catch you off guard.

Comment: @coredump: They only "cross validate" each other if you *don't* use automatic formatting. In which case you have two problems.

Comment: @JacquesB IMHO **accidentally** screwing up a brace placement is far less likely than screwing up indentation, especially for beginners.

Comment: @marstato: Why do you think that? Python have proven en excellent language for beginners.

Comment: @JacquesB because typing a closing brace is something that you actively do; not indenting enough is something you can forget to do. Of course you can forget to close a brace at the right time, but you'll have to do it eventually and get another chance to think about it. I guess python works good for beginners because it forces attention onto indentation.

Comment: @marsato, You do know that Python is either the #1 or #2 language for beginners (although JavaScript is close), and in terms of new projects in many places its #1.  Any bugs because of misplaced indentation are easily caught when in route of catching other bugs, but bugs do to inconsistent indentation are harder, and you can having extra { } or missing{ } when you accidentally use undo/redo/cut/paste/selected delete that you wouldn't have in whitespace sensitive languages.

Answer (score 14):

This is highly subjective and the cause for many a flame war. However:

Having symbols delimiting blocks *and* indentation **violates the DRY principle**, since you express the same information in two different ways. The existence of automated indentation tools is a *symptom* of this DRY violation: That you can automatically generate the indentation shows that it is redundant information, and it means the indentation and symbols *may* get out of sync which lead to misleading code.

The Python [Design and History FAQ](https://docs.python.org/3.5/faq/design.html) states this very clearly:

> **Why does Python use indentation for grouping of statements?**
>
> Guido van Rossum believes that using indentation for grouping is
>   extremely elegant and contributes a lot to the clarity of the average
>   Python program. Most people learn to love this feature after a while.
>
> Since there are no begin/end brackets there cannot be a disagreement
>   between grouping perceived by the parser and the human reader.

It is true that you cannot create an auto indentation tool for Python, but this is a good thing: It means you don't have redundancies in the syntax which you need automated tools to reconcile.

The tabs vs spaces is a legitimate concern in Python, and it is recommended to never mix tabs and spaces (for indentation) in the same codebase.

Python inherited the significant indentation from the (now obsolete) predecessor language ABC. ABC is one of the very few programming languages which have used **usability testing** to direct the design. So while discussions about syntax usually comes down to subjective opinions and personal preferences, the choice of significant indentation actually have a sounder foundation.

Comment: Double-entry accounting violates DRY too. Redundancy is sometimes a feature.

Comment: @coredump: True, but it is a deliberately designed redundancy. Most programming languages, including Python, contain deliberately chosen redundancies - e.g. the `pass` keyword which could be inferred automatically, but requiring it to be explicit helps discover mistakes. The accidental redundancy of having both begin/end symbols (for the compiler) and indentation (for the human reader) seem to cause more mistakes than it catches. At least this seems to be the view of van Rossum.

Comment: @coredump - Now I know why I'm not an accountant.

Comment: @coredump You miss COBOL's `PROCEDURE DIVISION.` too? I never can tell where where the `DATA DIVISION` ends and the procedures start in these newfangled languages.

Comment: @JacquesB "seem to cause more mistakes than it catches" this is definitely not how I experience it. I always reindent my code while editing it and simply seeing indentation contradicts what I had in mind is sufficient to prevent errors. The off-side rule looks nice and clean, and is arguably more user-friendly, but it is  less reliable in face of typos for equivalent errors in free-form languages.

Comment: @coredump: "seeing indentation contradicts what I had in mind is sufficient to prevent errors" - exactly.

Comment: Hm, I would say it's the other way around: Indenting every single line is an unnecessary repetition. A curly brace is just once and then valid for all following lines. Automatic indentation tools also can't be violating DRY, because it is just convention to that, but has nothing to do with the compiler

Comment: @MaxBinnewies: Automatic indentation tools *do* violate dry, since they modify the source code, so two representations of the same information have to be maintained. If the indentation was purely presentational in the IDE and no whitespace was actually inserted in the file, then it would not violate DRY, but no mainstream IDE works like that as far as I know.

Comment: @JacquesB: How can the way an IDE saves files break DRY(a design pattern that advises you, as a developer how to structure code)? Imagine an IDE that saves all source code files as .docx. That would obviously make no sense, but would that effect whether your code is DRY or not? Automatic indentation is purely presentational as it has no effect on compiled byte/machine-code, nor anything at runtime.

Comment: @MaxBinnewies: The DRY principle has nothing to do with whether something is compiled or not, or what format files are saved in. The DRY principle states "every piece of knowledge must have a single authoritative representation".

Comment: Exactly! Now you're getting it. In languages like C/Java/etc it doesn't matter if the developer/IDE/white space tool/compiler places whitespaces or not. The "single authoritative representation" of a code block in these languages are curly braces, white spaces are purely presentational. Now could you also please change your original answer to not confuse other people with wrong statements?

Comment: @MaxBinnewies: If code structure is indicated by both indentation and braces, and they can be changed independently (i.e. get out of sync), then you have a DRY violation since you have two independent representations of the code structure, not a single canonical. If you have a tool which guarantees that indentation is always synced to braces (or vice versa for that matter), then you don't have a DRY violation because you have a single authoritative source of the structure. What the compiler sees is beside the point.

Comment: While its true that your editor can derive indentation from your { }, the } makes the code far more "vertical" meaning more navigation is required to see your code.  I sometimes use x, y = 5, 10 and expressions instead of statements so that the code fits in the 2D box more "efficiently".  Lisp with parinfer, however, is awesome as you can edit your code like Python in the whitespace mode, but it keeps the } out and away so that your code isn't vertical, and it has a block mode for copy/pasting/editing.  https://shaunlebron.github.io/parinfer/

Answer (score 2):

Language designers choose syntactically significant whitespace because they believe (or at least think their potential users believe) that the semi-colons and braces add noise when reading code, harming productivity. Another common reason is that bad/inconsistent coding style harms readability - by forcing a common indentation scheme, the language has better readability over-all. That later reason is less important now that auto-formatting IDEs are more common, but can still apply.

Comment: I can see why one would consider semicolons and curly braces noise. But isn't it less productive to have to type 4 / 8 / 12 times space? And if you miss one (since they're invisible) you're in trouble.

Comment: That's why you use tabs instead of spaces, or an IDE that understands how to convert tabs into four-space blocks.

Comment: @K.Gkinis: Indents are not invisible. Only whitespace at the ends of lines is invisible, but this is not significant in any language. Only if you mix tabs and spaces will you get into trouble. So don't do that.

Comment: @JacquesB: the problem with visibility/invisibility of indentation is that as a human you often can't tell the difference between spaces and a tab, whereas the computer can and often does. So, while the indentation is visible, the way the computer interprets the indentation can be different. That's the real problem: when the computer treats the invisible characters differently than humans. Humans measure indentation as distance on a screen, computers may measure it as literal number of characters.  _that's_ the invisible part.

Comment: @BryanOakley: Yeah, this is why you shouldn't mix tabs and spaces in indentation.

Comment: @Telastyn: I disagree about "noise" characters harming readability. For example Python has a colon before blocks. This is arguably noise characters, but have been shown in usability tests to actually improve readability, which is why they are included in the language.

Comment: @JacquesB - oh, I absolutely agree. I find the explicit tokens to be much more readable.

Comment: @Telastyn: Oh I meant that I disagree that this is what the language designers believe. What you and I think is most readable is beside the point :-)

Comment: When you write if cond:<ENTER> Python IDEs auto indents just like typing in { in {} languages.  That extra } that is managed by your IDE makes can push code down so you can't see it.  Python/Haskell can tell you when you've mixed spaces and tabs btw so yeah you need to use the spaces 2 tabs feature in your editor.